# Binding real time data to my char via XAML

Tags: wpf, charts, telerik

I have this chart:

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart Name="myChart">
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
        <telerik:CartesianChartGrid MajorLinesVisibility="XY"/>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
        <telerik:LogarithmicAxis LogarithmBase="2"
                         Minimum="125" Maximum="8000"/>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
        <telerik:LinearAxis Maximum="10" Minimum="-130"/>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
        <telerik:ScatterLineSeries>
            <telerik:ScatterLineSeries.DataPoints>
                <telerik:ScatterDataPoint YValue="-40" XValue="125"/>
                <telerik:ScatterDataPoint YValue="-50" XValue="250"/>
                <telerik:ScatterDataPoint YValue="-60" XValue="500"/>
                <telerik:ScatterDataPoint YValue="-70" XValue="1000"/>
                <telerik:ScatterDataPoint YValue="-80" XValue="2000"/>
                <telerik:ScatterDataPoint YValue="-70" XValue="4000"/>
            </telerik:ScatterLineSeries.DataPoints>
        </telerik:ScatterLineSeries>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
</telerik:RadCartesianChart>
```

And in my code i have timer that receive data every second:

```
private Random random = null;
```

Create timer:

```
    random = new Random();
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

Timer tick:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int val = random.Next(0, 100);
    line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = val });
}
```

I all i want to to (i am totally new with WPF) is to replace my hard coded values in my `XAML` in the real time data that the timer received (the 'val' variable).

Comment: Are you using the MVVM pattern? Is you timer code in the code behind of the xaml?

Comment: my timer is define in the code and only in the code